# Form enctype="multipart/form-data" ignored on form post, content-type reverts to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: html, file-upload, content-type, multipartform-data

## Background statement and question

I have an HTML5 form with an input element with `type=”file”`.  I have set `enctype=”multipart/form-data”`.  On form post, however,  the content type is still `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.
Perhaps anybody has an idea of what is wrong?

---

## Here’s my code

### The portion of the code that is causing me headaches

```
<form action="/File/Upload" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#dup_smallSpinner" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#DocumentList" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form0" method="POST">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="JSfRE7YGCWMIc2xSU6FuI4e2PrRlmxNoUED9zn4p-IjGRYynOePvcWS8yaufucWY5f4EKpFmQBaZqtuyjS5zrn3MdtFiGtr5VV52-8vqAOY1" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="2" />    
        <div class="well col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dup_smallSpinner" style="display:none">
                        <img src="/Content/img/loading32x32.gif" />
                    </div>
                    <input id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">

                        <input type="submit" title="Upload" name="submit" formenctype="multipart/form-data" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="DocumentList">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: `data-ajax="true"` … that’s what’s wrong, I’d guess.

Comment: That is required in order for the AJAX partial postback to work.  Why would you say that is the problem?

Comment: Because normally AJAX doesn’t do file uploads – that requires a capable browser (HTML5 file API), and extra work to read the file contents via JS and preparing it for submit. Whether or not your lib handles that, I don’t know (because you didn’t tell us which one it is).

Comment: It's quite frustrating... one would think that after how many years of the www's existence it would be straightforward to upload files via ajax. I really do want to understand the mechanics behind all of this.  Any useful links that you know of in this regard?